# C Vector/ArrayList/LinkedList

Tags: c

I'm doing a little program in C and I'd need a kind of vector/ArrayList/LinkedList but I'm working with C. Any idea on how I could do that kind of thing in C?

I want to store structs and then append/remove some.

Comment: There's no such thing in the standard C library. People usually roll their own.

Comment: While the terms vector and ArrayList usually refer to the same datastructure (resizable array), a linked list is something completely different. So do you want a resizable array or a linked list?

Comment: And people shouldn't.  Glib has a perfectly good implementation here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html  And most Unix C libraries include an implementation of tsearch, which, although awkward to use, can be pressed into service as a list of elements.

Comment: @Michiel: Why not post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Considering the fact that the OP sounds like a beginner, I would suggest that he roll his own solution first, but also that there are tested, verified implementations available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For resizable arrays you can use `malloc()` and `realloc()`. These allow you to reserve (with `malloc()`) and resize (with `realloc()`) a certain amount of space on the heap. They're used this way:

```
int* a = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

if(a == NULL) {}     // malloc() was unable to allocate the memory, handle the
                     // error and DO NOT use this pointer anymore

// now you can treat a as a normal array of 10 ints:
a[4] = 51;

// suppose 10 ints aren't no more enough:
a = realloc(a, 20 * sizeof(int));

if(a == NULL) {}     // same thing as before

// here you have 20 ints, the previous 10 are still there
a[18] = a[4]

// don't forget to free the memory when you have finished:
free(a);
```

Just replace 'int' with your struct type. ;)

Comment: Since the question is tagged only with "C", it's questionable whether one should fill an example with unnecessary (and ugly!) casts that do more harm than good (by hiding errors, for example). Casting to `void*` is arguably *never* good practice! Also, error handling is important, and since there's no exceptions, you have to check the return values of both `malloc` and `realloc` (and not lose the original pointer!) Also, the call to `realloc` will not increase the buffer size on almost any computer (20 bytes is **very** rarely more than 10 ints).

Comment: Also, you have to change more than casts to make this work with other types. If, however, you had followed a better style (i.e. `type *ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr)` and similarly with `realloc`) you'd only ever need to change the type `type` in the declaration.

Comment: One shouldn't introduce malloc() and realloc() without introducing free()

Comment: @eq: I forgot the sizeof(int) in realloc(). ;) is it better now?

Comment: when the program closes, it frees memory, eh?

Comment: @user576488: The OS will claim all memory it gave to your program so don't free() won't kill anyone, but is better doing it.

Answer (score 6):

Use an existing implementation. There are billions. [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) is probably a good place to start, or [LibH](http://libh.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

I used @Conrad Meyer's answer. Downloaded latest [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) library from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.38/glib-2.38.2.tar.xz) and compiled it using [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/glib2.html) manual. To test Glib libraries I used [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/) test. You may have errors while compiling the test code. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90338/how-to-compile-a-helloworld-glib-program) will help you solve your problem.

Also I found that there is a some kind of memory leak in the test code. *Valgrind* result running the original code:

```
==20350== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20350==     in use at exit: 4,632 bytes in 12 blocks
==20350==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 0 frees, 4,632 bytes allocated
==20350== 
==20350== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20350==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20350==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20350==      possibly lost: 992 bytes in 4 blocks
==20350==    still reachable: 3,640 bytes in 8 blocks
==20350==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

So I inserted one line in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GList* list = NULL;
    list = g_list_append(list, "Hello world!");
    printf("The first item is '%s'\n", (char *)g_list_first(list)->data);
    g_list_free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

*Valgrind* new results:

```
==20310== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20310==     in use at exit: 4,632 bytes in 12 blocks
==20310==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 0 frees, 4,632 bytes allocated
==20310== 
==20310== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20310==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20310==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20310==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20310==    still reachable: 4,632 bytes in 12 blocks
==20310==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857638/660408) answer tells that there is no need to worry about `still reachable` memory.

Answer (score 2):

C does not come with any form of a standard collection (unlike higher-level languages such as C++ and Java) so you're left with a few options:

1. Use an existing one created by some group/some individual (as mentioned above)
2. Create your own

You'll need to consider exactly what you need for this program to determine what you use. From what you're asking for, you're probably looking for one of two options:

1. An array that will dynamically grow when you've allocated. Essentially, you need to maintain how many elements are contained within your array at that point. If at any point during insertion you are over the maximum amount of elements, you must create a new array, copy the elements into the new array, insert the new element and finally delete the old array. This tends to be faster in terms of access time (since it's indexable) but slow and memory-consuming if you over-allocate. See BlackBear's code for an example.
2. A linked list that dynamically grows by design. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly-.2C_doubly-.2C_and_multiply-linked_lists. This has the main advantage of no extra maintenance in the special case but the disadvantage of slow access (look at each element until you find the element you want).

See the Wikipedia page for more information on trade offs between the two kinds of data structures.

Comment: Is reallocating every time it's appended going to hurt?

Comment: @user576488: it's very slow. You can declare the array leaving some space unused in case you'll need it later

Comment: reallocating lets say with chunks of 10? would be better?

Comment: @user576488: yes. the larger the better

Comment: @user576488: common strategies for reallocation are arithmetic growth (ie adding a fixed number of elements) and geometric growth (ie multiplying the size by a fixed factor, eg doubling the size)