# How do I store continuously read in input from the standard input in C? Similar to `while (cin >> x)` in C++

Tags: arrays, c, input, user-input

How do I store continuously read in input from the standard input in C? Similar to `while (cin >> x)` in C++?

Say I want to store a set of integers into an array/vector with no predefined size. In C++, I can do:

```
vector<int> vec;
while (cin >> x) {
  vec.push_back(x);
}
```

I haven't found anything online something similar to `while (cin >> x)`.

The closest I've found for something similar to `while (cin >> x)` is:

```
int x;
while(scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
  // do stuffs
}
```

But what this does is continually read through every input, including using the `Enter` key in the terminal. So it doesn't stop reading input from the terminal.

Comment: A `std::vector` is a container that internally has a pointer to an array that was dynamically allocated. You can construct something like that yourself in C (e.g.: by using `realloc`)

Comment: I would have thought that `while(scanf("%d", &x) == 1)` was a *very* good match to `while (cin >> x)`.  Can you explain a little more how you're finding them different?

Comment: Is the main question here how to do the stream-of-integers input, or how to replicate a `std::vector`?  The question had been closed as a duplicate of [How to replicate vector in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694401) and [C Vector/ArrayList/LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701900), but it looks to me like the real question concerns the input, so I voted to reopen.  BICBW.

Comment: Both examples use `while()` so there's no difference there... Look at the _differences_ between the examples. C++ has a _magical_ `vector` object. You can't replace that with defining a single simple `int`... This is what you need to research... (as suggested by @UnholySheep: `realloc()`)

Comment: @SteveSummit yeah the main question is the stream-of-integer input. I'm finding them different because if I press the `Enter` key, it still asks for an input, instead of doing what I wanted the program to do with the input. My input consists of integers, and the program only stops asking for inputs if it's of type non-int (excluding whitespace)

Comment: You could use EOF (ctrl-d) to terminate input instead of a blank line with `scanf()`.  If you don't like how it ignores newline then read it line (of max size) by line with `fgets()` instead then parse the line probably writing your own parser (i.e. not `atoi()` if you want to detect errors) or use `sscanf()`.   vector block allocates, so you want to write a bit of code that reallocs with some factor (I forgot what the stl uses;  <2) when out of space.  There are a bunch of libraries out there too (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310205/any-library-like-stl-vector-map-in-c)

Comment: Also, don't overlook reading the whole thing as a string, then write a function to extract what you want. If your input is huge, it's easy to write to a file and you your function still works when you process file in blocks or mmap said file.

Comment: @neil_ruaro I just compared the `scanf` and `cin >> x` loops, and at least on my machine, they perform *identically*.  Single numbers on a line input as single numbers.  Blank lines are ignored.  Multiple numbers on a line input as multiple numbers.  Non-numeric input, or control-D, terminates.  This is all as I would expect.  As I understand it,  free-form stream input using `>>` in C++ is very, very similar, almost identical, to the free-form input that `scanf` does.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to do free-form `int` input in C versus C++, `scanf` is indeed a good choice.  This simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    while(scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", ++i, x);
    }
}
```

corresponds just about exactly to this simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    while (cin >> x) {
        cout << ++i << ": " << x << endl;
    }
}
```

For both programs, the input

```
11
22

33
44 55 66
x
```

yields the output

```
1: 11
2: 22
3: 33
4: 44
5: 55
6: 66
```

Note that, in both cases, blank lines are ignored, and multiple numbers on a line are read individually.  Non-numeric input (here `x`) terminates the input.

On Unix and Linux, control-D can also be used to terminate the input; on Windows, control-Z can also be used.

If the question is how to store the integers into an automatically-growing vector, see [How to replicate vector in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694401) or [C Vector/ArrayList/LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701900).