# glib: valgrind reporting 'still reachable' blocks after g_strsplit

Tags: c, valgrind, glib

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  const char * path = "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/";
  gchar ** parts = NULL;
  int i;

  parts = g_strsplit( (const gchar *) path, "/", 0 );

  for ( i = 0; parts[i]; i++ ) {
    if (parts[i][0] == '\0') {
      continue;
    }
    printf("part: %s\n", parts[i]);
  }

  g_strfreev( parts );
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this code through Valgrind, I get a bunch of 'still reachable' blocks:

```
==12924== 
==12924== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12924==     in use at exit: 4,252 bytes in 8 blocks
==12924==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 11 frees, 4,358 bytes allocated
==12924== 
==12924== 240 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
==12924==    at 0x4A04820: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:581)
==12924==    by 0x4A048D7: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:709)
==12924==    by 0x36A8255F87: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825680B: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8257DBD: g_slist_prepend (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825AB15: g_strsplit (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x4005C8: main (strsplit.c:10)
==12924== 
==12924== 252 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==12924==    at 0x4A04A28: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==12924==    by 0x36A8241707: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8255742: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825669D: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8257DBD: g_slist_prepend (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825AB15: g_strsplit (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x4005C8: main (strsplit.c:10)
==12924== 
==12924== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==12924==    at 0x4A04A28: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==12924==    by 0x36A8241707: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8255722: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825669D: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8257DBD: g_slist_prepend (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825AB15: g_strsplit (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x4005C8: main (strsplit.c:10)
==12924== 
==12924== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==12924==    at 0x4A04A28: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==12924==    by 0x36A8241707: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825578B: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825669D: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8257DBD: g_slist_prepend (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825AB15: g_strsplit (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x4005C8: main (strsplit.c:10)
==12924== 
==12924== 720 bytes in 3 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==12924==    at 0x4A04820: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:581)
==12924==    by 0x4A048D7: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:709)
==12924==    by 0x36A8255F87: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8256841: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8257DBD: g_slist_prepend (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825AB15: g_strsplit (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x4005C8: main (strsplit.c:10)
==12924== 
==12924== 2,032 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==12924==    at 0x4A04A28: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==12924==    by 0x36A8241707: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8256642: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A8257DBD: g_slist_prepend (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x36A825AB15: g_strsplit (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==12924==    by 0x4005C8: main (strsplit.c:10)
==12924== 
==12924== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12924==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12924==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12924==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12924==    still reachable: 4,252 bytes in 8 blocks
==12924==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12924== 
==12924== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12924== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

My question is:  did I not clean up properly or are these errors something that can be safely ignored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [valgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html),

> Because there are different kinds of leaks with different severities,
>   an interesting question is this: which leaks should be counted as true
>   "errors" and which should not?
>
> Definitely lost and possibly lost blocks are counted as true "errors".
>   Indirectly lost and still reachable blocks are not counted as true
>   "errors", even if --show-reachable=yes is specified and they are
>   printed; **this is because such blocks don't need direct fixing by the
>   programmer.**

So you can safely ignore these errors as these blocks will be anyways re-claimed at program exit.

Also read this SO thread which discussed Valgrind memory errors in detail

[Still Reachable Leak detected by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind)

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://aleksander.es/data/valgrind-memcheck.pdf) may help to understand which kind of leaks Valgrind/memcheck detects.

As for the issue itself, first don't run valgrind on a GLib-based program using the default slice-allocator in GLib, as that will give you lots of 'garbage' output in the valgrind log. Just run the program instructing GLib to use plain mallocs:

```
$ G_DEBUG=always-malloc valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes your-program your-args
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

 in g_slice_alloc () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0

(gdb) backtrace
 in g_slice_alloc () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
 in g_slist_prepend () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
 in g_strsplit () from /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
```

---

Guess, there is something going wrong with the allocation in glib.
Many other projects which use Glib also have such issues.

Comment: The comment is not helpful. Also, you may want to try recompiling your local glib-2.0 installation.