# valgrind reports leaks for mysql_real_connect

Tags: c++, mysql, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have the following code structure (The whole code is huge and I think this snippet is relevant to my problem),

```
MYSQL_RES *res_set;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL *connect;

int main()
{
 connect=mysql_init(NULL);
 mysql_real_connect(connect, NULL, "root", "suvp" ,"Employees" ,0,NULL,0);

 /*Other Code*/

 mysql_free_result(res_set);
 mysql_close(connect);
}
```

The variables for database connection are global. In my "Other Code" I make call to other functions which uses initialised `connect` (in `mysql_query` etc )and `row` and `res_set` when necessary. and as seen I free the result and close the connection at the end of main.

I reuse `res_set` (without freeing it each time) from one function to other. Will that cause an issue?

In all the functions that I use, the staments are similar

```
mysql_query(connect,myQuery.c_str())
res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);
row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
```

Valgrind reports this,

```
==4864== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4864==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4864==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4864==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4864==    still reachable: 99,954 bytes in 30 blocks
==4864==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Detailed errors point out to

```
mysql_real_connect
```

called from my main function.

As per this [page](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7619) calling `mysql_library_end()` is good practise. But then even after I call `mysql_library_end()` after closing my connection. Valgrind Says,

```
==5120== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5120==     in use at exit: 116,466 bytes in 34 blocks
==5120==   total heap usage: 95 allocs, 61 frees, 147,218 bytes allocated

==5120== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5120==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120==    still reachable: 116,466 bytes in 34 blocks
==5120==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

And as earlier, they all boil down to `mysql_real_connect`

The program runs fine. But there are problems indicated by valgrind. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably nothing. You have to read this. The first answer is very clarifying.

TL;DR: Still reachable is not a real "memory leak" but memory that when the program was about to terminate, there was still pointers to it in the program (pointers in your program not freed before program terminated).

[Still Reachable Leak detected by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind)