# Cairo and memory leaks fix with valgrind

Tags: c, cairo

In my program, even if do all the obvious housekeeping, such as calling `cairo_destroy()`, `cairo_surface_destroy()`..., `valgrind` always finds memory leaks, the leaks are in `cairo` dependencies (`freetype`, `pixman`, ...). How do I cleanup after `cairo`, so that `valgrind` won't detect any leaks, or are the leaks normal?

Sample output

```
==1861== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1861==     in use at exit: 1,996,663 bytes in 532 blocks
==1861==   total heap usage: 21,915 allocs, 21,383 frees, 95,411,698 bytes allocated
==1861== 
==1861== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1861==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1861==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1861==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1861==    still reachable: 1,996,663 bytes in 532 blocks
==1861==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1861== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1861== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1861== 
==1861== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1861== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1861== ERROR SUMMARY: 1961 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

UPDATE:

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind) says, the "leaks" are normal, does there exist a way to do the cleanup, so valgrind becomes happy?

Comment: I don't see any leaks: 'definitely lost, indirectly lost, possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks'.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, but in an ideal world, all allocated heap would be freed at program exit. That's what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: For cairo, there is cairo_debug_reset_static_data().

Comment: @UliSchlachter Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cairo there is `cairo_debug_reset_static_data()`.

While writing this as a comment, I was looking into pixman's source and the implementation of `_pixman_choose_implementation()` and apparently you cannot "clean up" pixman.

I have no clue about freetype.

Edit:
For fontconfig (related to freetype, so possibly interesting here), there is `FcFini()`.

Comment: This will have to do, unless someone comes up with something even better.

Comment: I build and link FreeType independently of cairo, and when my program terminates, I have no reachable FreeType blocks left, just pixman blocks.