# Still reachable with puts and printf

Tags: c, macos, valgrind

Valgrind is reporting the still reachable "error" on functions like printf and puts. I really don't know what to do about this. I need to get rid of it since it's a school project and there has to be no errors at all. How do I deal with this? From the report I can see those functions use `malloc`, but I always thought they handled the memory by themselves, right? 
I'm using mac OS X so maybe it's a problem between valgrind and the OS?

SAMPLE CODE: The error appears on any of the puts or printf that are used

```
void twittear(array_t* array_tweets, hash_t* hash, queue_t* queue_input){

    char* user = queue_see_first(queue_input);
    char key[1] = "@";

    if (!user || user[0] != key[0]) {
        puts("ERROR_WRONG_COMAND");
        return;
    }

    queue_t* queue_keys = queue_create();
    char* text = join_text(queue_input, queue_keys);

    if (!text) {
        puts("ERROR_TWEET_TOO_LONG");
            queue_destroy(queue_keys, NULL);
        return;
    }

    int id = new_tweet(array_tweets, text);
    while (!queue_is_empty(queue_keys))
        hash_tweet(hash, queue_dequeue(queue_keys), id);
    queue_destroy(queue_keys, NULL);
    printf("OK %d\n", id);
}
```

ERROR:

```
==1954== 16,384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 77 of 77
==1954==    at 0x47E1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==1954==    by 0x183855: __smakebuf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1954==    by 0x198217: __swsetup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1954==    by 0x1B1158: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1954==    by 0x1B16AF: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1954==    by 0x188B29: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1954==    by 0x18696F: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1954==    by 0x1000036F3: twittear (main.c:138)
==1954==    by 0x100003C8D: main (main.c:309
```

Comment: Hi I've just added some sample code!

Comment: What's the actual error? And are you sure it's not on the returns *following* `puts()`? i.e. does `queue_see_first()` allocate memory (returned to `user`) that should be freed before returning/exiting?

Comment: queue_input was previously created and is destroyed somewhere else.
queue_see_first just returns the pointer to the first element on the queue, when it's dequeued the user has to free it.
Even if it's not a real error I'd like to know what is going on, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26409611

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind

Comment: Yes I've seen those threads but none of them offer a solution and I can't see why in this case I get an error out of prints and puts and other cases not :/ why would these functions not free memory by themselves? I just need to understand what's going on better so I can get rid of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is somewhat glitchy on Mac OS X; it doesn't have complete suppressions for some system libraries. (That is, it doesn't properly ignore some "expected" leaks.) Results will frequently include some spurious results like this, as well as some buffer overruns resulting from optimizations in functions like `memcpy()`.

My advice? Avoid using valgrind on Mac OS X unless you are *very* familiar with the tool. Compile and test your application on a Linux system for best results.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the stdio library. A "Hello World" program is sufficient to reproduce it - just printf or fprintf to stdout or stderr. The first time you write to a FILE, it uses malloc to allocate an output buffer. This buffer allocation happens inside the __swsetup() function (download LibC source from Apple, you will see this in there; but actually, it is copied from FreeBSD, so many *BSD systems have the same function.) Now, when you call fclose() on the FILE, the buffer will be freed. The issue with standard streams (stdout, stderr), is one normally doesn't close them, as a result this buffer will normally never be freed.

You can make this "leak" go away by adding an fclose() on stdout and/or stderr before terminating your program. But honestly, there is no need to do that, you can just ignore it. This is a fixed sized buffer which is not going to grow in size, so it is not a "leak" as such. Closing stdout/stderr at the end of your program is not achieving anything useful.