# Memory leak with template for pointers and ints. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, templates, memory-leaks, valgrind

Getting to know C++, and trying to template a class to work with Ints and Pointers for a struct.
The output is as expected, but testing with valgrind there seems to be a memory leek, from an unfreed memory.

I believe it has something to do with the way i declare the list variable in the class init.

What am I missing and how can i fix it?
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T>
class List {
    T* list;

public:
    int length;

    List(int len) {
        list = new T[len];
        length = len;
    }

    virtual ~List() {
        delete[] list;
    }

    T get(int index) {
        return list[index];
    }

    void set(int index, T val) {
        list[index] = val;
    }
};
/*
    You shouldn't change the code below, unless you want to _temporarily_ change the main function while testing.
    Change it back when you're done.
*/
typedef struct Point_ {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

int main(){
    List<int> integers(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
        integers.set(i, i * 100);
        printf("%d ", integers.get(i));
    }
    printf("\n"); // this loop should print: 0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900

    List<Point *> points(5);
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        Point *p = new Point;
        p->x = i * 10;
        p->y = i * 100;
        points.set(i, p);
        printf("(%d, %d) ", points.get(i)->x, points.get(i)->y);
        delete p;
    }
    printf("\n"); // this loop should print: (0, 0) (10, 100) (20, 200) (30, 300) (40, 400)
}
```

compiled with g++ like this:

```
g++ -Wall p2_templates.cpp -o p2_templates
```

Used valgrind with this command:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./p2_templates
```

Getting this result from valgrind:

```
==22396== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22396== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22396== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22396== Command: ./p2_templates
==22396== 
0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 
(0, 0) (10, 100) (20, 200) (30, 300) (40, 400) 
==22396== 
==22396== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22396==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==22396==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 8 frees, 73,848 bytes allocated
==22396== 
==22396== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22396==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22396==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22396==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22396==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==22396==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22396== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22396== 
==22396== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22396== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Why not just use a `vector`?

Comment: What is `points.length`?

Comment: Why is your destructor `virtual`?

Comment: kinda doing homework.. doing the asigments from MIT website for learning C/C++.

Comment: @barakmanos can you expand on the vector thing?

Comment: And why that useless `new` and `delete` business in the `main`? Btw, `#include <stdio.h>` should be `#include <cstdio>`, the former is legal but deprecated since the first standard. Also, check out `<iostream>` which is the standard C++ I/O.

Comment: @or.ohev-zion He is talking about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which is the standard dynamically sized array in C++.

Comment: the virtual keyword, thought perhaps the destructor fails to destruct on of the List objects, so i made it virtual, although that has nothing to do with this matter, evidently. if you remove the virtual keyword, we get the same output.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Doesn't hurt the to link to the docs anyways, the sooner he dodges this homebrewed stuff the better. Honestly, I would have expected more from an institution like the MIT, but on the other hand, it's a *"website for learning C/C++"*. :/

Comment: I'm guessing one of the later lessons goes into all the things that are bad in main.

Comment: it seems that with std::vector there is no need to delete the array, vector takes care of it. but perhaps the memory leak has to do with the code in the main?

Comment: @ROX hopefully, though the `typedef`ed `struct` doesn't give me much hope of them diverging wildly from C with classes.

Comment: Why not try temporarily commenting out parts of main to see if you can narrow down where it leaks.

Comment: So far i replaced list declarion with a vector, and commented parts of main to seclude the memory leaks, still same result. i can post the code with vector and results from valgrind if necessary.

Comment: Valgrind's "still reachable" category is [for blocks which still have accessible pointers at program exit](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.errormsgs). You may want to go through their manual more carefully, OP, since it gives instructions on how to get more information about leaks.

Comment: wait, OP, what system are you running on? If it's Mac OS X, try commenting out the `printf` statements and running again. [valgrind occasionally finds potential leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846494/still-reachable-with-puts-and-printf) with stdio [on that OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409611/valgrind-showing-memory-leak-for-printf-and-unused-blocks).

Comment: tried commenting out the prints.. wasnt it. thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all read the valgrind output VERY CAREFULLY and ENTIRELY (and do everything what valgrind recommends). In your case the fragments of interest are:

> Rerun with **--leak-check=full** to see details of leaked memory
>
> **still reachable**: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks

You should also be aware of the following:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports (4.1.  My program uses the C++ STL and string classes. Valgrind reports '**still reachable**' memory leaks involving these classes at the exit of the program, but there should be none).

And if you have time you may strongly benefit from detailed understanding of this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks (4.2.8. Memory leak detection).

Finally you can find tons of useful info here: http://valgrind.org (valgrind homepage).

Answer (score 1):

A strong grasp of basic data structures is good! I encourage you to explore it fully.  Once you have grip on the basics then the STL can be very useful to take care of the busy work while you think about the hard problems.

There are no leaks in your code.  Valgrind is seeing the memory elsewhere, as noted you can use the --leak-check=full to get more details.  Its good that you are trying to understand those details.

This is a dangling pointer problem however.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T>
class List {
    T* list;

public:
    int length;

    List(int len) {
        list = new T[len];
        length = len;
    }

    virtual ~List() {
        delete[] list;
    }

    T get(int index) {
        return list[index];
    }

    void set(int index, T val) {
        list[index] = val;
    }
};
/*
    You shouldn't change the code below, unless you want to _temporarily_ change the main function while testing.
    Change it back when you're done.
*/
typedef struct Point_ {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

int main(){
    List<int> integers(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
        integers.set(i, i * 100);
        printf("%d ", integers.get(i));
    }
    printf("\n"); // this loop should print: 0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900

    List<Point *> points(5);
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        Point *p = new Point;
        p->x = i * 10;
        p->y = i * 100;
        points.set(i, p);
        printf("(%d, %d) ", points.get(i)->x, points.get(i)->y);
        delete p;
    }
    Point* fail = points.get(0);
    fail->x = 0;
    fail->y = 0;
    printf("\n"); // this loop should print: (0, 0) (10, 100) (20, 200) (30, 300) (40, 400)
}
```

Note that I added the 'fail' variable after the points loop to demonstrate the issue. The points variable is declared and populated fine but then the contents are deleted.  The List holds Point* rather than Point, as such when the delete occurs the pointer in the List is 'dangling'. Dangling pointer use will crash or corrupt the heap almost every time.   This is a common problem with the STL containers as well when holding pointers.

A big flaw in C++ is the heap management. Correctly using the heap is very difficult with the biggest problem being ownership hand off.  Dangling pointers or leaks often result from confusion on who owns the pointer.  There is a brief article here [Avoiding Leaks in C++](http://matthewericfisher.tumblr.com/post/4587587561/avoiding-memory-leaks-in-cc)

Running this program under Valgrind will show Invalid write errors. Give it a try.

Comment: I ran the valgrind test with the suggested flags and i did get write errors.

Comment: Right. Memory management is tricky in C++. Would appreciate an up vote if my answer was helpful. Thanks

Comment: @or.ohev-zion An up vote would be appreciated if my answer was helpful.