# How declaring a variable with malloc lead to lost bits?

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

First, I have ran valgrind to make sure that (on the default settings) there are zero errors.  Then, I decided to check for leaks with something like: `--leak-check=full`

I have code that looks something like `char* variable=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(in)+1));` and valgrind reports that memory is "definitely lost."

The only other line of code I have access to (this is in a library callback function) is the line of code where `in` is declared.  This is a function argument of type `void *` (though in this case I'm hoping we can safely assume the value to be null terminated.)

Comment: Since you haven't provided entire code, I cannot be accurate but it is possible you are not freeing up "variable" anywhere. Also, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061326/why-valgrind-report-my-memory-as-definitely-lost help in understanding your problem?

Comment: Annnnnnd of course.  I KNEW that that is how malloc works.  In fact I was counting on it elsewhere.. thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char * G;

int main()
{
   char * l = malloc(10);

   G = malloc(20);
}
```

The execution under *valgrind* gives :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
==11087== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11087== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11087== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11087== Command: ./a.out
==11087== 
==11087== 
==11087== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11087==     in use at exit: 30 bytes in 2 blocks
==11087==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 30 bytes allocated
==11087== 
==11087== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==11087==    at 0x4847568: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==11087==    by 0x10453: main (mm.c:7)
==11087== 
==11087== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11087==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==11087==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11087==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11087==    still reachable: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==11087==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11087== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==11087== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==11087== 
==11087== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11087== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

The `malloc(10)` is definitely lost because there is no way to access it at the end of the execution (here out of *main*)

The `malloc(20)` is not lost because still reachable through *G*

Comment: Whoah, lemme check before I accept your answer, I think that's it!

Comment: @user1833028 trust on _valgrind_, if it says _definitely lost_ that means there are ;-)

Comment: How does anything get "possibly" lost, can you tell me?

Comment: @user1833028 I cannot produce  that case in a normal code (look at http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks), but for  "indirectly lost" replace my code about _l_ by `char ** l = malloc(2*sizeof(char *)); /* definitively lost */` and 
`*l = malloc(10); /* indirectly lost */`