# valgrind says i have definitely lost block in very simple malloced code, and I can't figure why

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I was testing valgrind and came up to this code, which only mallocs structure.

```
#include "env.h"

int     main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    t_env   *env;
    int     i;

    env = malloc(sizeof(t_env));

    return (0);
}
```

```
typedef struct  s_env
{
    char        **global_env;
    int         global_size;
}               t_env;
```

I can't figure out why this is considered definitely lost.
Shouldn't it be considered still reachable?
Would be glad to teach me!

---

Sorry ,
I found out this behavior, that it's right to call definitely lost reading this article
[Why valgrind report my memory as "definitely lost"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061326/why-valgrind-report-my-memory-as-definitely-lost)

when it comes to global variable, and not freeing, then it's considered still reachable.
But when it's local variable, it's considered definitely lost.

Comment: Once the method returns, it's not reachable anymore and it's a valid warning. Calling `free(env)` is polite to the memory manager.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson ,thank you. I thought it should be considered Still reachable because `main(){}` had malloced memory. Must be confused with not free'd global variable.