# If in C++ objects with automatic storage are not destroyed by calling exit, what happens with this objects after leaving the program?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

On this site [(cplusplus.com)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) I read that objects with automatic storage are not destroyed by calling exit(). Does it mean that there will be a memory leak?
I know that when you reach the end of the automatic variable's scope they will be destroyed, but in this case does it mean that we don't reach the end of scope and simply leave the program?

---

I'm curious what will happen with memory in this example that I found in forums:

**C++ code**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    ~C()
    {
        std::cout<<"X"<<std::endl;
    }
};

void f()
{
    C c;
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Here the "X" was not outputted so destructor was not called. Can we say then that it is a memory leak?

---

EDIT:

Thank you for your responses. But I want to clarify something else. Assuming that the operating system will not release memory after completion of the program, does this mean that after the exit() call the object with automatic storage will cause a memory leak (because it will not be destroyed)? Or it may only occur when allocating memory from heap using, e.g., operator new?

Maybe I formulated the question not too clear, but I would like to know whether objects with automatic storage destroyed in any case, even if the program is not reached before the end of the block and interrupted by exit() call.

Comment: Trace through the calls. `main` calls `f` which constructs `c` then calls `exit` which then terminates the process. Now that the process has been terminated and removed from memory and all that jazz do you think the destructor of `C` is ever called on `c`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What REALLY happens when you don't free after malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc)

Comment: You're not allocating any memory - so what memory could you be leaking?

Answer (score 7):

Normal memory allocation cannot leak, because when the process exits all of its memory pages are cleaned up.  However, objects that clean up process-independent external resources (like files) in their destructor *can* leak them, for example:

```
class TempFile {
public:
   TempFile() { /* create a file on disk */ }
   ~TempFile() { /* delete the file from disk */ }
}
void foo() {
   TempFile tf;
   exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a memory leak in general; a modern OS will clean it though.

I would suggest to read the accepted answer below because we need to know what you meant by a "memory leak":

[Still Reachable Leak detected by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind)

Answer (score 1):

According to C++98 §18.3/8

When `exit`, only static objects are destroyed, and then `atexit` handlers are executed, openning streams are flushed and closed, and files created by `tmpfile` are removed. **Local automatic** objects are not destroyed.

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit 
>   Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage
>   duration are not called

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    C( const std::string &name ) :
        m_name( name ) { }
    ~C()
    {
        std::cout<< m_name << " destructor" <<std::endl;
    }
    std::string m_name;
};

static C c1( "Static C" );

void f()
{
    C c( "Local C" );
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All that is telling you is that *the destructor* is not called. Not that the memory leaks.