# Deconstruct const pointer?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, valgrind

It's probably very basic but I am stuck and simply don't know what the problem is.

The main code is predefined as a task. The goal is to use const as much as possible. The following constructor is just supposed to copy the literal string to the const m_data and that works fine but I am not able to free the memory - it always leaves 1 block. What am I missing?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "immstring.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace Util;

int main() 
{
  const ImmutableString s1("Hello");
}
```

immu.hpp

```
#include <cstring>
namespace Util {
class ImmutableString {
public:
    ImmutableString(const char* src);
    ~ImmutableString();

private:
    char* const m_data;
};
}
```

immu.cpp

```
#include "immstring.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
namespace Util 
{
ImmutableString::ImmutableString(const char* src)
    :m_data{strcpy(new char[strlen(src)+1],src)}{}

ImmutableString::~ImmutableString() 
{
    delete m_data;
}
}
```

Comment: `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: And better yet, [avoid `new` and `new[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/10077).

Comment: Please explain why you use `new[]` then `delete`.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with `const`?

Comment: Note that `char* const m_data` is not an immutable character string. It's an immutable pointer to a mutable character string. You likely want `const char* m_data;`.

Comment: That is true the title is a little misleading - although I tried delete [] m_data and still get: still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks

Comment: Is `s1` global or in the scope of `main`? Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: Note that "still reachable" doesn't necessarily mean there was a memory leak problem -- it might be deliberate.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: That's it - I was so focused on the getting a clean log that I didn't notice that delete [] provided no errors - "just" the 1 block. Thanks everyone this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave all array memories blocks you have to use delete like this :

```
delete[] m_data;
```

Thanks,
Robin.