# Still reachable memory but tried freeing memory

Tags: c, valgrind

Im trying to learn how malloc works with pointers and such and i've tried freeing my memory of pointer but when I check for memory leaks using valgrind it still says I have 32 bytes that are reachable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fib2(int* a);

int main()
{
  int *pointer;

  //allocates space for 2 elements for pointer
  pointer = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));

  //prints first two fibonacci values
  printf("0 1 ");

  //calls fib2 func and apsses pointer into it
  fib2(pointer);

  //frees pointer memory
  free(pointer);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}

//generates fibonacci sequence
void fib2(int* a)
{
  int i;

  //initial fibonacci array initialized
  a[0] = 0;
  a[1] = 1;

  //generates and calculates fibonacci sequence and prints
  for(i = 2; i < 12; i++)
  {
    a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
    printf("%d ", a[i]);

  }
}
```

**edit Valgrind output in text form as requested earlier

```
==5451== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5451== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5451== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info

==5451== Command: ./lab3
==5451==  0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 
==5451== 
==5451== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5451==     in use at exit: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==5451==   total heap usage: 50 allocs, 49 frees, 107,863 bytes allocated
==5451== 
==5451== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5451==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5451==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5451==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5451==    still reachable: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==5451==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5451== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==5451== 
==5451== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5451== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857638/1216776

Comment: You freed your pointer. It's probably an internal pointer used by `stdio`.

Comment: Your pointer points to 400 bytes, so it's not what the warning message is talking about.

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** and add the output from valgrind **as text**.

Comment: @Barmar no, not stdio, that is something even sillier, seems to be a forced libGLdispatch OpenGL library that is dynamically linked to the executable.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Right, I see that now in the report, but I don't see any code in the question that would be responsible for this.

Comment: @Barmar `LD_PRELOAD` maybe... :F

Comment: But my general point is correct: it's coming from a library outside the programmer's control, so there's not much they can do about it.

Comment: `Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory`

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out it was an issue with my Valgrind

Comment: How did you fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No fix, it's just an issue with Valgrind, can't do anything about it.