# c pthread still reachables

Tags: c, pthreads, valgrind

I'm using pthread in my program. It runs fine but valgrind detects still reachables. Always the same bytes: 1654, 4 blocks. Always the same functions visible in valgrind.

Valgrind log:

```
==29908== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29908== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29908== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29908== Command: ./a.out
==29908== Parent PID: 23902
==29908== 
==29908== 
==29908== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29908==     in use at exit: 1,654 bytes in 4 blocks
==29908==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 4 frees, 2,526 bytes allocated
==29908== 
==29908== 36 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==29908==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29908==    by 0x401F5CE: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==29908==    by 0x4019A81: _dl_load_cache_lookup (dl-cache.c:338)
==29908==    by 0x400A989: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2102)
==29908==    by 0x4015D36: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:513)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x40155F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==29908==    by 0x49DE860: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x49DF982: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==29908==    by 0x486E99A: pthread_cancel_init (unwind-forcedunwind.c:53)
==29908== 
==29908== 36 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==29908==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29908==    by 0x400D5A7: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:196)
==29908==    by 0x4006E96: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:997)
==29908==    by 0x400A61A: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2236)
==29908==    by 0x4015D36: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:513)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x40155F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==29908==    by 0x49DE860: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x49DF982: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==29908==    by 0x486E99A: pthread_cancel_init (unwind-forcedunwind.c:53)
==29908== 
==29908== 384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==29908==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29908==    by 0x401330A: _dl_check_map_versions (dl-version.c:274)
==29908==    by 0x40160EC: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:577)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x40155F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==29908==    by 0x49DE860: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x49DF982: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==29908==    by 0x486E99A: pthread_cancel_init (unwind-forcedunwind.c:53)
==29908==    by 0x486EBB3: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (unwind-forcedunwind.c:127)
==29908==    by 0x486CF05: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:121)
==29908== 
==29908== 1,198 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==29908==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29908==    by 0x400D273: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:89)
==29908==    by 0x4006E96: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:997)
==29908==    by 0x400A61A: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2236)
==29908==    by 0x4015D36: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:513)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x40155F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==29908==    by 0x49DE860: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==29908==    by 0x49DF8B7: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==29908==    by 0x49DF982: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==29908==    by 0x49DE994: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==29908==    by 0x486E99A: pthread_cancel_init (unwind-forcedunwind.c:53)
==29908== 
==29908== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29908==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29908==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29908==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29908==    still reachable: 1,654 bytes in 4 blocks
==29908==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29908== 
==29908== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==29908== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I limit the program to 1 thread, I never get any still reachables. If I limit it to something low like 2, I sometimes do, sometimes don't. Anything high (48) means I almost always get still reachables.

I managed to reproduce the problem without much code, as follows. What am I doing wrong? If I am doing nothing wrong and it's just pthread things, why is it making still reachables? And why is it semi-random depending on amount of threads?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUMTHREADS  2 //can be anything higher than 1 to cause still reachables

void    *thread(void *arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void)
{
    int         i;
    pthread_t   threads[NUMTHREADS];

    i = -1;
    while (++i < NUMTHREADS)
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, &thread, NULL);
    i = -1;
    while (++i < NUMTHREADS)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: **Still reachable** doesn't always mean **leaked**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Still Reachable Leak detected by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840582/still-reachable-leak-detected-by-valgrind)

Comment: I know still reachables aren't necessarily catastrophic or even bad. My question is rather: **why** is pthread making these? Why are they random? Is there any way to avoid them? My program is a school assignment and I have to be able to understand and justify what's going on. I'm also just curious. The solution offered in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856938/17661256 does not work in my case: I am joining all the threads and they should be freed when the program returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `thread` function, you are doing:

```
pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Replace with:

```
return (void *) 0;
```

---

> Perfect, thank you. Any downsides to exiting threads this way? Do you also have any idea what in pthread is causing these still reachables or why this solution works? –
> Modin

The [linux, at least] implementation of `pthread_create` does *not* put the argument you give it for the thread function (e.g. in your case `thread`) as the thread start address given to the `clone` syscall. It gives the pointer to an internal/hidden "helper" start function that does:

1. Some initialization of thread local storage, etc (which may need to call `malloc`).
2. Invokes the "real" function
3. TLS cleanup/destructors

If we call `pthread_exit`, we are bypassing step (3).

To see the details, we'd have to get the `glibc` source and look in `nptl/pthread_create.c` to the 10 or so steps that get bypassed by not returning.

Personally, I've always "unwound" my call stack to use the `return (void *)` and only called `pthread_exit` as an "abort"

---

**Edit:**

If we look at the source for `pthread_exit`, it calls `__do_cancel` [an internal function]. So, it's like doing:

```
pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
```

---

Given the [modified] program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUMTHREADS  8                   // can be anything higher than 1 to cause still reachables

void *
thread(void *arg)
{
#if DOEXIT
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
#else
    return (void *) 0;
#endif
}

int
main(void)
{
    int i;
    pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];

    i = -1;
    while (++i < NUMTHREADS)
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, &thread, NULL);
    i = -1;
    while (++i < NUMTHREADS)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    return (0);
}
```

---

Note in the test outputs below, the `valgrind` command is:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -s ./fix0
```

---

Here is the output compiled with `-DDOEXIT=1` (that does `pthread_exit`):

```
==1659955== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1659955== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1659955== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1659955== Command: ./fix0
==1659955==
==1659955==
==1659955== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1659955==     in use at exit: 1,616 bytes in 4 blocks
==1659955==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 9 frees, 3,848 bytes allocated
==1659955==
==1659955== 21 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==1659955==    at 0x483780B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==1659955==    by 0x401C13D: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==1659955==    by 0x4016D0A: _dl_load_cache_lookup (dl-cache.c:306)
==1659955==    by 0x4009592: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2107)
==1659955==    by 0x4013A7D: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:217)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x401363D: _dl_open (dl-open.c:588)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5250: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5E02: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5356: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==1659955==    by 0x49F53E9: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==1659955==
==1659955== 21 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==1659955==    at 0x483780B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==1659955==    by 0x400BCEF: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:163)
==1659955==    by 0x400649F: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:1002)
==1659955==    by 0x4009319: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2241)
==1659955==    by 0x4013A7D: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:217)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x401363D: _dl_open (dl-open.c:588)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5250: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5E02: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5356: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==1659955==    by 0x49F53E9: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==1659955==
==1659955== 384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==1659955==    at 0x4839B1A: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==1659955==    by 0x401142F: _dl_check_map_versions (dl-version.c:274)
==1659955==    by 0x4013B25: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:266)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x401363D: _dl_open (dl-open.c:588)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5250: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5E02: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5356: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==1659955==    by 0x49F53E9: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==1659955==    by 0x48AE45A: pthread_cancel_init (unwind-forcedunwind.c:53)
==1659955==    by 0x48AE673: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (unwind-forcedunwind.c:127)
==1659955==
==1659955== 1,190 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==1659955==    at 0x4839B1A: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==1659955==    by 0x400BA11: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:73)
==1659955==    by 0x400649F: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:1002)
==1659955==    by 0x4009319: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2241)
==1659955==    by 0x4013A7D: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:217)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x401363D: _dl_open (dl-open.c:588)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5250: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5D66: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5E02: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==1659955==    by 0x49F5356: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==1659955==    by 0x49F53E9: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==1659955==
==1659955== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1659955==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1659955==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1659955==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1659955==    still reachable: 1,616 bytes in 4 blocks
==1659955==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1659955==
==1659955== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

Here is the output when compiled with `-DDOEXIT=0` (does `return (void *) 0;`):

```
==1660133== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1660133== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1660133== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1660133== Command: ./fix0
==1660133==
==1660133==
==1660133== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1660133==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1660133==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 2,176 bytes allocated
==1660133==
==1660133== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1660133==
==1660133== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Re "*`(void *) 0`*", or the clearer `NULL`, which you already use elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Any downsides to exiting threads this way? Do you also have any idea what in pthread is causing these still reachables or why this solution works?

Comment: @ikegami No, `(void *) 0` is correct here because it's a return/exit code that can also be a pointer. To be more explicit, `(void *) EXIT_SUCCESS` or `(void *) 7` or `(void *) EINVAL`, `&new_global_error`, etc. depending upon the individual programmer's convention for the given program.

Comment: @Craig Estey, It IS a pointer. While it could be an exit code, it is NOT an exit code in the program in question. The value is not used. So claiming that `(void *) 0` makes sense is completely wrong. Furthermore, note that none of `(void *) EXIT_SUCCESS` or `(void *) 7` or `(void *) EINVAL` are safe.

Comment: Finally, `(void *) 0` doesn't even mean zero stored in pointer variable as you seem to think. It means `NULL`, and it might not be zero.