# Why does one of my ways of passing retval (void *) to pthread_exit() give unexpected results?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, void-pointers, pthread-exit

Today is my first day working with threads. I am struggling to understand why I am unable to pass the retval (type: void *) in **both** of the following ways below (i.e., only one way will give expected results as I illustrate/describe below).

I will provide a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <string.h>

static void *threadFunction(void *arg)
{
  printf("thread1: hello from thread...\n");
  char array_of_chars[] = "goodbye...";
  char *ptr_to_first_element_in_array_of_chars = array_of_chars;
  
  void *exitStatus_ptr;
  exitStatus_ptr = ptr_to_first_element_in_array_of_chars;

  printf("thread1: thread about to die...\n");
  //pthread_exit( exitStatus_ptr ); /** denote as Line 17 **/
  pthread_exit((void *) "goodbye..."); /** denote as Line 18 **/
}
int main(int argc, int *argv[]) //main thread
{

  pthread_t thread1;

  void *targetThread_exitStatus;
  int s; 

  s = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, threadFunction, NULL); 

  if (s != 0) 
  {
    perror("pthread_create() error...");
  }
  
  s = pthread_join(thread1, &targetThread_exitStatus);
  
  if (s != 0)
  {
    perror("pthread_join() error...");
  }

  printf("main thread: retval from thread is: %s\n", (char*) targetThread_exitStatus);
  printf("main thread: thread about to die...\n");

  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

When I compile the above source code on my Linux terminal:

```
gcc code.c -lpthread -o code
```

And then execute:

```
./code
```

I get the following output:

```
thread1: hello from thread...
thread1: thread about to die...
main thread: retval from thread is: goodbye...
main thread: thread about to die...
```

**However,** if I add a single-line comment to Line 18 above, and I remove the single-line comment from Line 17 above, the output is as follows:

```
thread1: hello from thread...
thread1: thread about to die...
main thread: retval from thread is: 
main thread: thread about to die...
```

As you can see, the retval (i.e., goodbye...) is not displayed.

Given that a string is stored as an array of characters in C, and arrays "decay" to pointers (i.e., a pointer to the first element in the array), why does the above code only produce expected results for one way of passing the retval and not the other (i.e., it does not produce expected results when the single-line comment is added to Line 18 and removed from Line 17)?

Comment: `char array_of_chars[]` is a local variable. It ceases to exist when the function returns. Changing it to `static char array_of_chars[] = ...` should work, since `static` variables exist for the entire lifetime of the program.

Comment: In `main`, it's not applicable/advisable to do `pthread_exit((void *) 0)`. This is only for threads created with `pthread_create`. From `main`, do: `return 0;` or `exit(0);`

Comment: @CraigEstey Why does the Linux man pages advise against this? "To allow other threads to continue execution, the main thread should terminate by calling pthread_exit() rather than exit(3)." See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html.

Comment: That's only for those _rare_ occasions where you want to terminate `main` (the master thread) and let the others continue (i.e. `main` did _not_ call `pthread_join` on them). You already joined the threads. `pthread_exit` does an internal equivalent of `pthread_cancel` on itself. See my recent answer: [c pthreads still reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610521/5382650)

Comment: It does _not_ advise this. It advises: _After the last thread in a process terminates, the process terminates as by calling exit(3) with an exit status of zero; thus, process-shared resources are released and functions registered using atexit(3) are called._ In the notes section, it's saying _if_ you want threads to continue but you want to terminate main, you _can_ do this. But, again, that's rare. Maybe if you detached the subthreads. But, since 2004, I've _never_ done this [never needed to].

Comment: @CraigEstey This is very clear now. Thank you. My comment lacked the appropriate context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
pthread_exit( exitStatus_ptr ); /** denote as Line 17 **/
```

passes a pointer to a local variable to pthread_exit. When you want to retreive that value in `main()`, that pointer is invalid as it points to something on the stack in `threadFunction` - which has been destroyed when `pthread_join()` returns. So you get undefined behavior.

The man page for `pthread_exit` mentions this explicitly:

> The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling
> thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after
> the thread terminates.

This on the other hand:

```
pthread_exit((void *) "goodbye...");
```

gives a pointer to a string literal to `pthread_exit()`. String literals live for the duration of the process, so there's no issue using that pointer in `main()` after `pthread_join`